# how to display number of lines in running shell file

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, echo

For my assignment i need to display the current number of lines inside of a shell file, below i have implemented the `wc -l` command inside of my program but instead of displaying the number of lines my shell echo's out the actual command and filename.  How would I overcome this?

```
echo "Hello my name is: Roosevelt Mendieta"
echo "My user name is: $USER"
echo "Todays date and time is: `date`"
echo "This file has: " wc -l mendietaRPgm4.sh  "lines of code"
read -p "Please enter any number " number
TIME=2
echo "Your number $number * 2 = $(($number * $TIME))"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "This file has: " wc -l mendietaRPgm4.sh  "lines of code"
```

This is `echo` command with 5 strings given as arguments ( and 5 because of the double quotes ). What you want is to use `$(...)` command substitution - whatever command is inside will run and its output will replace `$(...)`.

```
echo "This file has: " $( wc -l mendietaRPgm4.sh ) "lines of code"
```

This is closer, but not ideal, because `wc -l file.txt` will output filename. For example

```
$ wc -l /etc/passwd
47 /etc/passwd
```

Now, if you redirect the file into stdin of `wc` command, it won't output the filename ( since `stdin` technically has no filename ).

```
echo "This file has: " $( wc -l < mendietaRPgm4.sh ) "lines of code"
```

This now is proper. For brownie points, I would recommend reading [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html) to find out what variables you can use to refer to the script itself. Because currently, your script aims to hard-code the script name within itself, and that's not flexible nor practical. Once the script is renamed, the command will produce errors. But that's an extra exercise for the readers.

Comment: i appreciate the in-depth explanation, please be my professor!

Comment: @RooseveltMendieta Let me know if you college is hiring ;) I don't have a degree though